# Pass .csv file as parameter file for expdp Oracle 11.2.0.4.0

Tags: oracle, export, expdp

Can we use .csv file as parameter file for expdp ?

Ex: `expdp scott/xxx@dev parameter=table_full.csv`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot.  I'm not entirely sure what you are after here - I'm assuming that you want to unload a table in CSV format ?  If that's the case, then an easy way would be to download sqcl

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/downloads/index.html

It's free and small (10mb), and then its just a case of running a query against your table

```
SQL> spool my_output_file.dat
SQL> select /*csv*/ * from scott.emp;
"EMPNO","ENAME","JOB","MGR","HIREDATE","SAL","COMM","DEPTNO"
7369,"SMITH","CLERK",7902,17/DEC/80,800,,20
7499,"ALLEN","SALESMAN",7698,20/FEB/81,1600,300,30
7521,"WARD","SALESMAN",7698,22/FEB/81,1250,500,30
7566,"JONES","MANAGER",7839,02/APR/81,2975,,20
7654,"MARTIN","SALESMAN",7698,28/SEP/81,1250,1400,30
7698,"BLAKE","MANAGER",7839,01/MAY/81,2850,,30
7782,"CLARK","MANAGER",7839,09/JUN/81,2450,,10
7788,"SCOTT","ANALYST",7566,09/DEC/82,3000,,20
7839,"KING","PRESIDENT",,17/NOV/81,5000,,10
7844,"TURNER","SALESMAN",7698,08/SEP/81,1500,,30
7876,"ADAMS","CLERK",7788,12/JAN/83,1100,,20
7900,"JAMES","CLERK",7698,03/DEC/81,950,,30
7902,"FORD","ANALYST",7566,03/DEC/81,3000,,20
7934,"MILLER","CLERK",7782,23/JAN/82,1300,,10

14 rows selected.
```